# Formatting of table output by removing extra spaces between each columns

Tags: oracle

I have a table output like,

```
|111      | abc1   | abc2                                     
| Y       | abc3   | 02-JAN-21
```

And I would like to have the table output to be displayed as

```
111|abc1|abc2|Y|abc3|02-JAN-21
```

Any SET options in oracle sql?

Comment: How is that string produced? Perhaps the easiest is just [Replace](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/REPLACE.html#GUID-1A79BDDF-2D3B-4AD4-98E7-985B2E59DA6B) function.

Comment: What is your oracle version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your intention is to trim the space between resulted columns, then you can use the code mentioned below. REGEXP_REPLACE will work

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('|111      | abc1   | abc2                                     
| Y       | abc3   | 02-JAN-21','(\|)([[:space:]]*)(\S+)(([[:space:]]*))','\1\3') FROM dual;
```

Output:

```
|111|abc1|abc2|Y|abc3|02-JAN-21
```

Note: I did not see any newline character so haven't replaced it. If you have new line character consider replacing that as well

Answer (score 0):

To me, it looks like SQL*Plus output which is result of a `SELECT` statement that selects data which is supposed to be a **single line**. Why? Because of different datatypes; `abc2` and `02-JAN-21` can't fit into the same datatype.

If that's so, as if `linesize` is set to a low value. For example:

```
SQL> set linesize 25
SQL> select empno, ename, job, hiredate from emp where rownum < 3;

     EMPNO ENAME
---------- ----------
JOB       HIREDATE
--------- --------
      7369 SMITH
CLERK     17.12.80

      7499 ALLEN
SALESMAN  20.02.81


SQL>
```

But, if you enlarge `linesize`, it looks better:

```
SQL> set linesize 80
SQL> select empno, ename, job, hiredate from emp where rownum < 3;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB       HIREDATE
---------- ---------- --------- --------
      7369 SMITH      CLERK     17.12.80
      7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN  20.02.81

SQL>
```